# Проверка залогинен ли пользователь на Java. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как проверить с помощью java залогинен ли пользователь на сайте Wordpress? Страницы кэшируются W3TC.

Comment: java не имеет никакого отношения к ВП. И причем тут кеш-плаг?

Comment: @SeVlad он, скорее всего, имеет ввиду Javascript

Comment: @KAGGDesign, скорее всего нужно дать человеку подумать.. А  если кто-то "путает" пол с полынью то это явно говорит, о том что.. не чем и говорить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress использует куки вида `wordpress_logged_in_длинная_hex_строка` для хранения информации о том, что пользователь залогинен на сайте.

Вы можете в js проверить, что такого вида куки существует и поверить, что пользователь её не подделал.

Для нормальной проверки нужно делать ajax-запрос, в котором вызывать `is_user_logged_in()`.